# IIFE's in angular controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm running into errors as a newbie in angular 1.5 and lower. I'm practicing with several online courses and all are using different versions of angular 1. I'm trying to stay close to John Papa's style guide and specifically to the use of IIFE's and Controller As but I keep having issues. Question is about wrapping controllers in separate files inside IIFE's

```
(function() { 

          angular
               .module('app')
               .controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

           function MyCtrl() {
              var vm = this;
              vm.title = 'hello world';
      })();
```

Is this always advisable or are there situations where this type of code will break execution?

Comment: It's an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) not an IFFE

Comment: Seems like `MyCtrl()`'s `}` closing bracket is missing

Comment: No reason using IIFE for each would cause issues. What specific errors are being thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason to use an IIFE is to not pollute the global scope.

If your code was not wrapped with an IIFE, then the parent scope would contain the variable **MyCtrl**. We want to keep MyCtrl private because you would never call the function yourself.

Now your question might be, *"If all this code is private, and nothing outside this scope can access **MyCtrl** to invoke or use it, what's the point? What am I even doing?"*

The reason this doesn't "break execution" is because we are doing **only** what we need, and letting Angular take it from there.

If you read your code, what you're really doing is saying:

> *"Hey, Angular. Take the already-defined module called **'app'** and
>   give it a controller which I have defined as **MyCtrl**. Name that
>   controller **'MyCtrl'**."*

That's all your code needs to do. You've given Angular a function to use as a controller for a specific module, and no other part of your code should know about it.

Comment: sometimes a good descriptive layman's terms answer is what is needed without a lot of technical jargon +1

Comment: yeah thanks. always appreciated over the short 'duh' answers. :)